# TCP Socket : Why does my C++ TCP client in Unreal Engine receive a null character at the end of messages from a C# TCP server?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, byte, unreal-engine5

This is my server code in C# :

```
// send a message
string str = "Hello World;";
byte[] strBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
int strLength = strBytes.Length;

// Allocate a buffer to hold the entire message
byte[] buffer = new byte[4 + strLength];

// Convert the string length to a 4-byte array in network byte order (big-endian)
byte[] strLengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(strLength));
Array.Copy(strLengthBytes, 0, buffer, 0, 4);

// Copy the string data to the buffer
Array.Copy(strBytes, 0, buffer, 4, strLength);

// Send the buffer in a single packet
stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

Console.WriteLine("Sent " + str);
```

This is my client code in unreal engine c++ :

```
void ATcpManager::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

    
    uint32_t DataSize = 0;
    TArray<uint8> DataBuffer;

    if (socket->HasPendingData(DataSize))
    {
        // Wait for the int32 prefix to arrive
        if (DataSize > 4)
        {
            FPlatformProcess::Sleep(0.01f);
        }

        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Received DataSize: %i"), DataSize);

        // Read the int32 prefix
        int32_t BytesRead = 0;
        bool bReadSuccess = socket->Recv(reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(&DataSize), sizeof(DataSize), BytesRead);

    
        if (bReadSuccess)
        {
            DataSize = ntohl(DataSize);
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("New DataSize: %i"), DataSize);
        

            uint32_t StrDataSize = 0;
            // Wait for the string to arrive
            while (socket->HasPendingData(StrDataSize) && StrDataSize < DataSize)
            {
                FPlatformProcess::Sleep(0.01f);
            }


            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("StrDataSize Arrived"));

            // Read the string
            DataBuffer.SetNumUninitialized(StrDataSize);
            BytesRead = 0;
            bReadSuccess = socket->Recv(DataBuffer.GetData(), StrDataSize, BytesRead);

            if (bReadSuccess && BytesRead == StrDataSize)
            {
                FString Message = FString::Printf(TEXT("%s"), UTF8_TO_TCHAR(DataBuffer.GetData()));
                UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Received message: %s"), *Message);
                OnDataReceived(Message);
            }
            else
            {
                UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Failed to read string data"));
            }
        
        }
        else
        {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Failed to read int32 prefix"));
        }
    }
```

This is the output I get sometimes (20% chances) :

```
LogTemp: Warning: Received DataSize: 16
LogTemp: Warning: New DataSize: 12
LogTemp: Warning: StrDataSize Arrived
LogTemp: Warning: Received message: Hello World;¶
```

The last character could be some random character from the charset. In some very rare occasions it has more characters at the end.

80% of the time the output is fine. I guess i should wait untill there is just the correct amount (>=) of bytes in the socket buffer from HasPendingData(), and then read that exact amount no less no more. But im scared that the buffer receives some random bytes due to cosmic rays or the cern opening portals to the underworld. Can someone help.

Im expecting this to output a normal text of fixed length, with no additional characters.

I tried debugging as much as possible. I asked chatGPT for guidance but its knowledge of sockets, is quite limited, and its knowledge in general lacks accuracy on the outer boundaries of its comfort zone, and spits outdated and irrelevant infos from other projects, like functions that dont even exist in objects im working with.

Comment: You didn't null-terminate the string after receiving it. The data size shown at the client end is clearly exactly the number of actual characters in the source string, without a terminator. For the client to use this data in functions that expect a null-terminated character sequence, you must add the terminator manually to the end of the buffer. This analysis was brought to you by an actual human with experience writing software, not a computer program. Please don't turn to ChatGPT for debugging help. It mostly knows how to regurgitate and reassemble stuff that it saw on the internet.

Comment: On a side note: after reading the prefix integer, you are waiting for the full string bytes to arrive before reading them, which is good. But, you are not waiting for the full prefix integer to arrive before reading it, so you could end up with a garbage value at times. You need a similar while loop for the prefix length, too.

Comment: i added '\0' to the string i sent from C#
string str = "Hello World;\0";
Now there is no more problems with that string i receive.
Ill do the loop to wait for data and read it properly.

Comment: "I asked chatGPT for guidance" is this the new norm? I don't relish having to comment newbie questions with `[ask]`, `[tour]`, `[example]` and now `[chatgpt]`.